# How to create two different search views for one model?

Tags: xml, odoo-8

Odoo version 8

I tried

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="list_action_view1">
        <field name="sequence" eval="1"/>
        <field name="view_mode">search</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="search_view1"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="list_action1"/>
    </record>
```

but it says 'search' is invalid. With tree and form it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Search views are used to filter other view's content, you don't put "search" at `view_mode`.

If what you need are two sets of filter and group-by options, then you can create something like below.

```
<!-- The first set of filter and group-by options. -->
<record id="search1" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Search 1</field>
    <field name="model">module.name</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <!-- Filter Options -->
            <field name="field1" string="Field 1"/>
            <field name="field1" string="Field 2"/>
            <!-- Group By Options -->
            <group string="Group By" name="groupby">
                <filter name="by_state" string="State" context="{'group_by': 'state'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- The second set of filter and group-by options. -->
<record id="search2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Search 2</field>
    <field name="model">module.name</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <!-- Filter Options -->
            <field name="field1" string="Field 3"/>
            <field name="field1" string="Field 4"/>
            <!-- Group By Options -->
            <group string="Group By" name="groupby">
                <filter name="by_priority" string="Priority" context="{'group_by': 'priority'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

If you have multiple menus for the module like below and need to have the content filtered.

Tasks

Tasks - All Tasks

Tasks - My To Do

```
<!-- All Tasks -->
<record id="action_task_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">All Tasks</field>
    <field name="res_model">module.name</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="search1"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create a new task</p>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- My To Do -->
<record id="action_task_my_to_do" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">All Tasks</field>
    <field name="res_model">module.name</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="search1"/>
    <field name="domain">[('current_at_id.user_id.id','=',uid)]</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create a new task</p>
    </field>
</record>
```

You can also have each menu using different set of filter and group-by options by setting the `search_view_id`.